# How can I do the following dataframe transformation in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, etl

Can someone help me with transforming the following table using a PYTHON function?

I need 2 new columns: A "follower Type" which will have entries as organic or paid and a "Follower count" which has the values corresponding to the type of follower.

Current Table -

| org | organic follower | paid follower | start date | stop date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 2 | 0 | 1634169600000 | 1634256000000 |
| One | -1 | 0 | 1634256000000 | 1634342400000 |

Desired Table -

| org | start date | stop date | Follower Type | Follower Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1634169600000 | 1634256000000 | Organic | 2 |
| One | 1634169600000 | 1634256000000 | Paid | 0 |
| One | 1634256000000 | 1634342400000 | Organic | -1 |
| One | 1634256000000 | 1634342400000 | Paid | 0 |

If anybody knows how to do this, please do let me know.
Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use reindex to change column order
'''
column_names = ["C", "A", "B"]
df = df.reindex(columns=column_names)

'''
Like below you can add columns to existing dataframe

df[newcolumn]=formula

Comment: I don't want to change the column order. I want to add new columns basis condition on existing columns